# MySQL: Trying to update to 5.5

Tags: mysql, mysql-5, mysql-5.5

I've followed [this instructions](http://www.ovaistariq.net/490/a-step-by-step-guide-to-upgrading-to-mysql-5-5/), but after `mysqld --skip-grant-tables --user=mysql`, I'm getting this:

```
110913 20:29:18 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/my-laptop.lower-test
110913 20:29:18 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/my-laptop.lower-test
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 2)
110913 20:29:18 [ERROR] Aborting
110913 20:29:18 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

what I think it could be normal because the tutorial ask to do "rm -R /var/lib/mysql" on the step before. So I then create /var/lib/mysql, execute again "mysqld --skip......" and I get this:

```
110913 20:32:07 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
110913 20:32:07  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

This is my /etc/my.cnf:

```
 # The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
user            = mysql
#password    = your_password
port        = 3306
socket        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
socket        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir         = /usr/local/mysql
datadir         = /usr/local/mysql/data
tmpdir          = /tmp
log_error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log 
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 256M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 256
sort_buffer_size = 1M
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 4M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size= 16M
# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
thread_concurrency = 8
```

I have ubuntu 10.10.

Any idea?

Javi

Answer (score 2):

> The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.

When you recreated /var/lib/mysql, you need to make sure the `/var/lib/mysql` directory is owned and writeable by the `mysql` user.

Answer (score 2):

Once you get your access rights back, don't forget to run [mysql_install_db](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-install-db.html).

It will create the `mysql` schema and place it in `/var/lib/mysql/mysql`

Please comment out your `datadir` if you do not want the data in `/usr/local/mysql/data`

Also, run this

```
mkdir /var/log/mysql
chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql
mkdir /var/run/mysqld
chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are using Ubuntu and your datadir is not in the standard `/var/lib/mysql` directory as `/usr/local/mysql/data` means that **apparmor** is probably kicking you in the balls.

Check this [post](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-change-the-mysql-data-default-directory.html).

You could also check diagnostics in `/var/log/syslog` for apparmor messages.  This last bit is useful because if you are using symbolic links, the messages in `/var/log/syslog` will tell you exactly what you need to put inside the `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` file (you need to add two lines).